# SQL Select Query to retrieve data from 2 Tables -show 0 not i table1 or table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by

I have 2 tables as below

```
TABLE_1

Date         Code   Time   Weight
01-09-2018      1   AM        100
01-09-2018      1   AM        120
01-09-2018      2   AM         80
01-09-2018      4   AM        135
02-09-2018      1   AM         50
02-09-2018      2   AM        110
02-09-2018      3   AM        115


TABLE_2

Date         Code   Time    Weight
01-09-2018      1   PM        110
01-09-2018      2   PM        115
01-09-2018      3   PM        125
01-09-2018      4   PM        100
02-09-2018      1   PM        130
02-09-2018      3   PM         50
02-09-2018      1   PM         75
```

Desired Result

```
Date         Code    AM    PM
01-09-2018      1   220   110
01-09-2018      2    80   115
01-09-2018      3     0   125
01-09-2018      4   135   100
02-09-2018      1    50   205
02-09-2018      2   110     0
02-09-2018      3   115    50
```

I need MS-SQL Select Query for this output.

Comment: Please describe the logic you use to create your needed result.  Then show us you you have tried.  See [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be easier to understand by grouping first:

```
select 
  Coalesce(t1.[date], t2.[date]) as [date],
  Coalesce(t1.code, t2.code) as code,
  Coalesce(Sum_am, 0) as [am],
  Coalesce(Sum_pm, 0) as [pm]
From
  (Select [date], code, sum(weight) as sum_am from table1 group by [date], code) t1
  Full outer join 
  (Select [date], code, sum(weight) as sum_pm from table2 group by [date], code) t2
  on t1.code =t2.code and t1.[date]=t2.[date]
```

Comment: This one is perfect and easy to understand. Thank you. Caius Jard. Good Work.

Answer (score 1):

use  left join and conditional aggregation

```
select t1.date, t1.code, 
       sum(case when t1.Time='AM' then t1.weight else 0 end ) as AM,
       sum(case when t2.Time='PM' then t2.weight else 0 end ) as PM
  from table1 t1 lef join table2 t2 on t1.code =t2.code and t1.date=t2.date
 group by t1.date, t1.code
```

Or same you can write by using cte

```
with t1 as

(select date,code,time,sum(weight) as w from table1
group by date,code
),
t2 as
(
select date,code,time,sum(weight) as w from table2
group by date,code
) select t1.date,t1.code, max(case when t1.time='AM' then t1.w end)  as AM,
         max(case when t2.time='PM' then t1.w end) as PM
          from t1 left join t2 on t1.code=t2.code and t1.date=t2.date
           group by t1.date,t1.code
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e7e0bf11006a2b04602ca9f0a4071ed0

Comment: Ambiguous column name 'date'.
Ambiguous column name 'code'.

Comment: Zaynul I think this should be solved by left joining both tables onto a calendar table/arbitrary rows generation of dates.. but could also full outer join it..?

Comment: @SatheshKumar https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5dd51020940dfd4c7a7cc90018b84d21 check this result shows correct

Comment: @SatheshKumar https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e7e0bf11006a2b04602ca9f0a4071ed0 check this

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of a pivot table. Modern RDBMS do all the work for you in one statement (see below).

First, there is no reason to split the data into two tables based on the AM/PM distinction. It is not a good idea. Even if this is a simplified version of a large application with massive data that requires partitioned tables, you should set that up so that queries can be done against one master table.

So, let's put all the data into Table 1.

```
insert into t1 values('2018-09-01',1,'AM',100),
('2018-09-01',1,'AM',120),
('2018-09-01',2,'AM',80),
('2018-09-02',1,'AM',50),
('2018-09-02',2,'AM',110),
('2018-09-01',1,'PM',110),
('2018-09-01',2,'PM',115);
```

Now let's [google](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) for the `PIVOT` command syntax. (This will *certainly* vary for other vendors; I don't think it's part of the SQL Standard, at least as usually implemented.)

Presto!

```
select * FROM t1 
PIVOT (SUM(weight) FOR [time] in ([AM], [PM])) AS tz;
```

```
date1   code    AM  PM
01/09/2018 00:00:00 1   220 110
02/09/2018 00:00:00 1   50

01/09/2018 00:00:00 2   80  115
02/09/2018 00:00:00 2   110
```

(You can use this as a subquery and `COALESCE` if you really need to replace the blanks in PM with zeroes. Also, if you really need two tables, use a subquery to just `UNION` them together before using `PIVOT`.)